# PostgreSQL index on multiple columns, when is it too much?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, composite-index, b-tree-index

Using PostgreSQL 9.6

I have a table with some values I want to filter on and order by time:

- a timestamp (may be range selected in the UI)
- status string (only a few known values for now, also selectable in the UI)
- context (scope of the data in the UI)

I wonder if I should have:

1. A btree index on (context, status) + separate index on time
2. OR A btree index on (context, status, time)
3. OR A btree index on each ?
4. OR A btree index on (time, status, context), for small time ranges ?

I suspect number 1 is the best option, context + status will allow to filter out values and then it will scan the time index.
I created number 1 concurrently on my data and saw some improvements but how do you decide between each approach, are there some guidelines ?

One of the queries looks more or less like:

```
select * from event
where severity = 'WARNING' and 
fk_context = 1359544
order by timestamp LIMIT 30; // Other one has timestamp > ...
```

Another one is looking for a timerange.
I looks like postgres uses multiple indexes, one with (fk_context, severity, timestamp) and then uses (severity, time) index, but it also depends on the limit.

Comment: Up to 32 columns can be specified. This is a hard limit. Your puprose should define your needs. Check queries you want to run against and chose the right index. I don't think there possibly could be generic guide for your 1,2,3,4 questons

Comment: Yes I presume it highly depends on the needs of the user interface. I will probably end up with more than one index for the various cases if performance is still an issue.

Comment: It would help if you provided an example of the `where` clause.

Comment: Sorry my question is not very specific ... I wanted to know how to approach this in general. It seems you must tailor indexes for each possible case and postgres will figure out what is best to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear.  If you have three potential conditions:

```
where timestamp between @a and @b order by time
where status = @s order by time
where context = @c order by time
```

Then you want three indexes:  `(timestamp, time)`, `(status, time)`, and `(context, time)`.

If the conditions are:

```
where timestamp between @a and @b and
      status = @s and
      context = @c
order by time
```

Then you want one index, `(status, context, timestamp, time)`.

And there are other possibilities consistent with your description.

Comment: ok I see so I probably have to build a lot of indexes for the different queries.

Comment: I don't think the last example is correct; the `timestamp` column should not be the first. It might be good to mention that a multi-column index can be used with a condition that uses the leading index columns.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . Good catch.  I made up the examples, so I really should have had the indexes aligned with the `where` clauses.

Comment: Actually, I think there is another problem with the second example: The `time` column is useless, because it cannot be used for sorting. If the index scans through the `timestamp` entries for a given `status` and `context`, it will get results that are not necessarily orderd by `time`, so a sort cannot be avoided.